# Getting useful errors from Typescript/Angular2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am working through the Angular2 TypeScript [Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html). At some point we actively create an error. Basically the tutorial asks to write some html that calls an undefined variable. It indicates that my console should show:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [null]
```

However what I get in Safari and Chromium is about [500 lines of stack dumps](https://postimg.org/image/dlcpjtmjl/) (This is one page load and it triggered 17 errors!)

I have run through the tutorial from install exactly so my setup should be correct. How can I get a cleaner error?  I can infer the issue for sure but I'd rather not have 500 lines of errors for every typo I do. Could end up crashing my browser :)

I am new to TS so perhaps there is a setting I need to adjust some debug setting?

Comment: Looks like the error is in the  AppComponent, can you post that in your question?

Comment: @JS_astronauts - it is. And I know what it is as I indicated. The tutorial makes you create an error. I am not looking to fix it but trying to understand why the tutorial says my console shows one error (granted they may not have pasted the whole thing) but surely 17 errors with stack dumps is a bit much for omitting an ngIf. It may be the way they have their test server setup but Id like to turn off all this dumping